# Armhf emulator/assembler ide?

Tags: user-interface, assembly, arm, ide

So in a class I'm in, we have raspberry pi 4's that we are SSHing into in order to write and execute raw ARMhf assembly. I just wanted to ask if anyone knows of an IDE that offers sort of elevated experience when writing assembly code instead of doing it via command line? I do have Raspbian installed on my raspberry pi and I just use a text editor to write my code. However, debugging a complicated program via the command line is something I wholeheartedly want to avoid. If anyone knows of any GUI based IDE that offers this, I would very much like to know. As a side note, I'm almost tempted to learn x86 assembly so that I can use Visual Studio for writing and debugging in place of the unfavorable alternative with Armhf. Thanks!

Comment: As a beginner, I recommend you to stick with the commandline setup you have right now.  You'll learn much more this way.

Comment: I would avoid x86 as a learning tool, arm is much better to start with than x86.  I would start with a pizero if possible or at least in aarch32 bit mode if you have to use a pi-4.   there are many free tools out there. which ones did you try?  I would also recommend command line, but YMMV.

Comment: Learning a 2nd ISA while you still barely know ARM is probably not a good idea.  Once you're comfortable with how one ISA is designed and how it works, understanding which things are the same and which things are different design decisions (and which are just syntax differences, not real differences in how the machine works) will be much easier.  I don't think you'd find it easier to write + debug x86 asm and then port it to ARM, although it is plausible (they both have condition codes).  Presumably you're writing pretty simple stuff so the implementation details are as hard as the algorithm.

Comment: Using Eclipse CDT+GDB Hardware Debugging support (for remote debugging)  with a makefile-base project on your PC and gdbserver on your target would work - see for example [here](https://www.96boards.org/blog/eclipse-remote-development-debugging/). If your code is loosely coupled, and want to write/test reasonably small portions of code/subroutines, you may use an online Armv7 IDE/emulator such as [this one](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm).